# Call a WebMethod with HTTPS url

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web, webmethod

C# side

```
[WebMethod]
public static string IsLoadComplete()
{
    return LoadComplete.ToString();
}
```

JS side

```
PageMethods.IsLoadComplete(function (state) {
    if(state == "True")
    {
      [...]
    }
});
```

if i test running in VS is everything ok.
When i publish on Azure and use HTTPS the "state" is always false.

There is something to set to call the WebMethod with HTTPS?

Comment: This might be useful https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: But i don't use a custom domain, i use https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net